# ActionListener from controller doesn't trigger

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I have an MVC with swing project with two views, a model and a controller.

The controller has as fields a list of models, and a list of views.
I tried to add a listener on a button from one of my views:

```
private void initializeNewOrderListeners() {
    NewOrderView view = (NewOrderView) views.get(0);
    JButton addOrderBtn = view.getAddOrderBtn();
    addOrderBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    });
}
```

I made sure that I don't have other order listeners in my `NewOrderView` class, however, the action is not getting triggered when I press the button.

I moved the code from the controller to the `NewOrderView` class, where I created the button and everything works normal when I press it.

What am I missing? Why the ActionListener is not getting registred from the Controller?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the view, but my initial thought was that the action listener should be added on the EDT.  Also, from a design perspective, I would discourage exposing any of the view's widgets.  When I do MVP/MVC I have the view add it's own action listeners and notify the presenter/controller because I prefer the view to be completely slave to the presenter/controller.  That being said, I have also seen examples where the view exposes an addXXXListener which avoids exposing view widgets

Comment: Maybe the reference to the view you are getting is not a reference to the same view instance that is actually displayed in a window. There could be many reasons this is not working: you need to create and post a [MCVE].